# シェルを用いてAndroidのインテントをadbから投げるには

Tags: android, bash

シェルを用いてAndroidのインテントをadbから投げるにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

adbからインテントをBroadcastしたいのですが、am start以下の書き方がわからないため、ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
adb shell
am start -hoge
```

アプリでインテントを投げている部分の抜粋

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btn1.isChecked()) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MeasurementMainReceiver.class);
            sendIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_STAET_MEASUREMENT);
            sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
```

Manifestファイル

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jp.hoge.tools"
android:versionCode="6"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="jp.hoge.tools.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    <receiver
        android:name="jp.hoge.tools.measure.MeasurementMainReceiver" >
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="jp.hoge.tools.measure.MeasurementService"
        >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="jp.hoge.tools.measure.measure1.Measure1Service"
        >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="jp.hoge.tools.measure.measure2.Measure2Service"
        >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="jp.hoge.tools.measure.log.MeasureLogService"
        >
    </service>

  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

サンプルを実装してみたのでご参照ください。
掲題のコマンドは次の通りです。
`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.ACTION_START_MEASUREMENT`

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.ACTION_START_MEASUREMENT  -e "Button" "onClick"`

実装にあたり、broadcastで投げている`Action`を取得すべく、
AndroidManifestのreceiverを一部修正いたしました。
このままだとセキュリティ上問題があるので
exportedの設定なり、[LocalBroadcastManager](http://qiita.com/amay077/items/830db7f0a535eba5e6a4)の使用を検討するなり、
追加検討をお願いいたします。

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jp.hoge.tools"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="jp.hoge.tools.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="jp.hoge.tools.measure.MeasurementMainReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_START_MEASUREMENT"/>
                    </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package jp.hoge.tools;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import jp.hoge.tools.measure.MeasurementMainReceiver;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String ACTION_START_MEASUREMENT =
"android.intent.action.ACTION_START_MEASUREMENT";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(layout);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MeasurementMainReceiver.class);
            sendIntent.setAction(ACTION_START_MEASUREMENT);
            sendIntent.putExtra("Button", "onClick");
            sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
        }
    });
    layout.addView(button);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MeasurementMainReceiver

```
package jp.hoge.tools.measure;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by hogehoge on 1/27/15.
 */
public class MeasurementMainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("TAG",intent.getAction());
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if(extras == null){
        Log.e("TAG","adbから呼ばれた");
    }else{
        Log.e("TAG",extras.getString("Button")+"から呼ばれた");
    }


}
}
```

ボタン押下した時のログ: onClickから呼ばれた
ADBコマンドを投げた時のログ: adbから呼ばれた

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 無事動作確認がとれました。どうもありがとうございます。
LocalBroadcastManagerの使用を検討します。